# Proper way to create a method in a parent class that's only supposed to be used by its children?

Tags: java, methods, architecture, overriding

I have several children of a parent class. I want the parent to implement a method that returns data. However, that data can only ever be correctly populated by the children.

Is this the ideal way to do this in Java? Is there a way to make it so that only the children can call the method?

```
public class MyParent {
    public MyData getData() {

    }
}

public class MyChildA extends MyParent {
    @override
    public MyData getData() {

    }
}
```

Comment: use an abstract class/method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out, abstract classes.

An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like this:

`abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);`

If a class includes abstract methods, then the class itself must be declared abstract, as in:

```
public abstract class GraphicObject {
   // declare fields
   // declare nonabstract methods
   abstract void draw();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parent class an Abstract class.

```
public abstract class MyParent {
    public abstract void getData();
}

public class MyChildA extends MyParent {
    @Override
    public void getData() {
        // statements
    }
}
```

Your question was a bit ambiguous so I don't know if this is what you were looking for.